# Hypothesis of Lorentz-Fitzgerald contraction

Tags: special-relativity

What is the exact difference between Lorentz contraction (of SR) and Fitzgerald-Lorentz contraction?
As my book says the latter was refused after Kennedy and Thorndike experiment. But they both argue that bodies experience a contraction in the direction of motion. So what is actually the real clash between the two of them?

Comment: When I Google this it appears that *Lorentz contraction* and *Fitzgerald-Lorentz contraction* are the same thing. can you provide a link or citation to a source that suggests they are different phenomena?

Comment: I could, but my book is in Catalan so it won't be helpful. Anyway, what did Kennedy and Thorndike experiment prove? As my book states, Fitzgerald hypothesis had to be abandonded after repeating M-M experiment with interferometer arms of different lenght.

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up. [The Kennedy and Thorndike experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy%E2%80%93Thorndike_experiment) showed that Lorentz/Fitzgerald-Lorentz contraction was not enough and there had to be time dilation as well. *Lorentz contraction* and *Fitzgerald-Lorentz contraction* are the same thing by different names.

Answer (score 1):

http://books.google.com/books?id=JokgnS1JtmMC 
 Banesh Hoffmann, Relativity and Its Roots, p. 106: "The effect is mutual. Each of us finds the other's lengths in the direction of our relative motion contracted. When FitzGerald and Lorentz and Poincaré spoke of a contraction, they thought of it as arising from motion through the ether. Undoubtedly they silently assumed that someone at rest in the ether would find that moving lengths were contracted but that a moving observer would find that lengths at rest in the ether were expanded compared with his own. And the even greater silence of these scientists about the slowing of clocks shows that in spite of their mathematical equations being the same as Einstein's, the idea of a reciprocal slowing of clocks was foreign to their views."